# Авто масштаб карты для окон разных размеров

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Когда отображаю новую карту в сжатом окне браузера то отображается только кусок карты.
Так отображается когда окно раскрыто 100%

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так отображается когда окно раскрыто 50%

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и вот так (**как нужно**) когда нажимаю стрелочки вверху справа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код который у меня отвечает за центровку. он отлично отрабатывает когда много элементов и экран раскрыт на 100%

```
myMap.setBounds(myMap.geoObjects.getBounds(), {
            checkZoomRange: true, zoomMargin: 35})
```

Comment: Судя по всему у вас высоты контейнера карты задана не в процентах от высоты страницы. Соберите минимальный пример воспроизводящий проблему.

Comment: да вы правы оказались у меня стоял height 1100px поставил 100% и все заработало